# Stopwatch app using Dojo

Tags: javascript, datetime, dojo

Here is the [link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7b9S/66/). This is my first app using Dojo. Any comments/feedback is highly appreciated.

```
dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true};

resetStopwatch();

require(["dijit/form/ToggleButton", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/domReady!"], function(ToggleButton, Button, dom, domAttr){

    var timeUpdate;

    var toggleButton = new ToggleButton({
        showLabel: true,
        checked: false,
        label: "Start",
        onChange: function() {
            if (this.get('label') == "Start") {
                this.set('label', 'Stop');

                var milliseconds = seconds = minutes = hours = 0;

                timeUpdate = updateTime(domAttr, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            } 
            else if (this.get('label') == "Resume") {
                this.set('label', 'Stop');
                // fetch current time in the stopwatch
                prev_milliseconds = parseInt(domAttr.get("milliseconds", "innerHTML"));
                prev_seconds      = parseInt(domAttr.get("seconds", "innerHTML"));
                prev_minutes      = parseInt(domAttr.get("minutes", "innerHTML"));
                prev_hours        = parseInt(domAttr.get("hours", "innerHTML"));
                timeUpdate = updateTime(domAttr, prev_hours, prev_minutes, prev_seconds, prev_milliseconds);

            }
            else if (this.get('label') == "Stop"){
                this.set('label', 'Resume');
                clearInterval(timeUpdate);
            }
        }
    }, "start_stop_resume");

    var resetButton = new Button({
        label: "Reset",
        onClick: function(){
            toggleButton.set('label', "Start");
            clearInterval(timeUpdate);
            resetStopwatch();        
            resumeFlag = false;
        }
    }, "reset");
});

function updateTime(domAttr, prev_hours, prev_minutes, prev_seconds, prev_milliseconds){
    var startTime = new Date();
    timeUpdate = setInterval(function(){
        var timeElapsed = new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime();

        // calculate hours                
        hours = parseInt(timeElapsed/1000/60/60) + prev_hours;
        hours = prependZero(hours);
        domAttr.set("hours", "innerHTML", hours + " : ");

        // calculate minutes
        minutes = parseInt(timeElapsed/1000/60) + prev_minutes;
        if(minutes > 60)
            minutes = minutes % 60;
        minutes = prependZero(minutes);
        domAttr.set("minutes", "innerHTML", minutes + " : ");

        // calculate seconds
        seconds = parseInt(timeElapsed/1000) + prev_seconds;
        if(seconds > 60)
            seconds = seconds % 60;
        seconds = prependZero(seconds);
        domAttr.set("seconds", "innerHTML", seconds + " :: ");

        // calculate milliseconds 
        milliseconds = timeElapsed + prev_milliseconds;
        milliseconds = prependZero(milliseconds);
        if(milliseconds > 1000)
            milliseconds = milliseconds % 1000;
        if(milliseconds < 10)
            milliseconds = "00" + milliseconds.toString();
        else if(milliseconds < 100)
            milliseconds = "0" + milliseconds.toString();                
        domAttr.set("milliseconds", "innerHTML", milliseconds);

    },25);  // update time in stopwatch after every 25ms

    return timeUpdate;

}

function resetStopwatch(){
    require(["dojo/dom-attr"], function(domAttr){
        domAttr.set("hours",        "innerHTML", "00 : ");
        domAttr.set("minutes",      "innerHTML", "00 : ");
        domAttr.set("seconds",      "innerHTML", "00 :: ");
        domAttr.set("milliseconds", "innerHTML", "000");
    });
}

function prependZero(time){
    if(time < 10){
        time = "0" + time.toString();
        return time;
    }
    else
        return time;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tinkered a bit with the fiddle, I have the following observations:

- If you were to place the colons in the HTML, then you would no longer need to concatenate the colons into the time fields:

  > ```
  > <div id="stopwatch"> 
  >   <span id="hours"></span>:
  >   <span id="minutes"></span>:
  >   <span id="seconds"></span>::
  >   <span id="milliseconds"></span>
  > </div>
  > ```
- You could generalize `prependZero` so that it works for both seconds and milliseconds by passing the requested length:

  > ```
  >   function prependZero( time, length ){
  >       time = time + "";
  >       while( time.length < length ){
  >       time = '0' + time;
  >     }
  >     return time;
  >   }
  > ```

  or a more Golfic version which calculates the amount of zeroes that will be required:

  ```
  function prependZero2( time, length ){
      time = time + "";
      return new Array( Math.max( length - time.length + 1 , 0 ) ).join("0") + time;
  }
  ```
- `if(minutes > 60) minutes = minutes % 60;` is the same as `minutes = minutes % 60;` is the same as `minutes %= 60;`.
- Your code would be much cleaner if you split out time calculations from prettyfying the numbers.

  You could have a function that is dedicated to time calculations:

  ```
  function updateTime(domAttr, prev_hours, prev_minutes, prev_seconds, prev_milliseconds){
    var startTime = new Date();
    timeUpdate = setInterval(function(){
      var timeElapsed = new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime();

      // calculate hours                
      hours = parseInt(timeElapsed/1000/60/60) + prev_hours;

      // calculate minutes
      minutes = parseInt(timeElapsed/1000/60) + prev_minutes;
      minutes %= 60;

      // calculate seconds
      seconds = parseInt(timeElapsed/1000) + prev_seconds;
      seconds %= 60;

      // calculate milliseconds 
      milliseconds = timeElapsed + prev_milliseconds;
      milliseconds %= 1000;

      setStopwatch( hours , minutes , seconds , milliseconds );

    },25);  // update time in stopwatch after every 25ms

    return timeUpdate;
  }
  ```

  and a function that just updates the DOM:

  ```
  function setStopwatch( hours , minutes , seconds , milliseconds ){
      require(["dojo/dom-attr"], function(domAttr){
          domAttr.set("hours"       , "innerHTML", prependZero( hours, 2 ) );
          domAttr.set("minutes"     , "innerHTML", prependZero( minutes, 2 ) );
          domAttr.set("seconds"     , "innerHTML", prependZero( seconds, 2 ) );
          domAttr.set("milliseconds", "innerHTML", prependZero( milliseconds, 3 ) );
      });
  }
  ```

  `resetStopwatch` then becomes as simple as

  ```
  function resetStopwatch(){
      setStopwatch( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
  }
  ```
- A very minor nitpicking, but the `require` array is hard to read, you should figure out how Dojo proposes you should indent that array.
- Another nitpicking is that you trust the DOM as your data model (you retrieve the values from the labels when you hit <kbd>Resume</kbd>), that is a bad practice in general, but acceptable for a timer project.

You can check the end result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/konijn_gmail_com/P7b9S/70/).